# Generating data from a hypothetical model

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

Let say I have below model

$y_{i,t} = 1 + X_1 + X_2 + {\gamma}_i + \epsilon_{i,t}, \epsilon_{i,t} \sim N \left(0, 1 \right), {\gamma}_i \sim N \left(0, \gamma \right)$

Here, the panel it is represented by suffix $i$ and there is time dependent measures for each $i$ which is represented by $t$

Another constraint is that, within each panel all observations have correlation coefficient as 0.65.

Based on this model, I need to generate 100 datapoints for further analysis.

Can you please help on pointer how I can I generate data based on above data generation process using *R*?

Comment: $\gamma_i$ is generated from a normal distribution with variance $\gamma$?

Comment: What are $X_1$ and $X_2$?  Would the correlation coefficient refer to the correlation between $y_{i,t}$ and $y_{i,s}$ for all $i$ and all $t\ne s$?  Shall we presume (as is strongly implied) that all explicitly named random variables are independent?

Comment: @whuber I only know that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are 2 exogenous variables (fixed effect). For your remanning questions, yes all are correct

Comment: This looks like some admixture of mathematical and programming notation, making it difficult to understand.  Perhaps you mean to write $$y_{i,t}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{i,1} + \beta_2 X_{i,2} + \gamma_i + \epsilon_{i,t}.$$ If not, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @whuber Your notation is perfect. The main issue I am finding in generating realisations is how to accommodate the correlation of 0.65

Comment: Okay, just one more followup question: are you assuming all the explicitly named random variables are independent?  If so, are you willing to let $\gamma$ be determined by the correlation (because it would be)?  Or do you wish to specify $\gamma;$ and if so, exactly in what way do you intend to relax the independence conditions?

Comment: I think it is moe prudent to adjust $\gamma$ in such a way the said correlation is equal to 0.65

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes the standard deviation of the Normal distribution you're generating $\gamma_i$ from is **NOT** $\gamma$.

You could generate data by defining a few function in R similar to this:

```
epsilonGenerator <- function() {
    eps_i = rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1) 
    return eps_i
}

gammaGenerator <- function(stdev) {
    gamma_i = rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=stdev)
    return gamma_i
}

dataGenerator <- function(X1,X2) {
    y_i = 1 + X1 + X2 + gammaGenerator(stdev) + epsilonGenerator()
    return y_i
}
```

Then simply call dataGenerator for each each pair of X1 and X2

Comment: Many thanks. How are we ensuring the constraint that states `Another constraint is that, within each panel all observations have correlation coefficient as 0.65.`?

Comment: Are X1 and X2 supposed to have correlation = 0.65? Because then we would need to look at how X1 and X2 are generated.

Comment: Actually I am not sure. It is not clear from the model documentation. However, being exogenous variables should not they be uncorrelated to avoid multicolinearity?

Comment: exogenous variables are independent, but they could still be correlated and cause multicollinearity